# free gui tool to export and import data from and to relational databases

Tags: database, relational-database, etl, eclipse-dtp, dbeaver

I'm searching free (as in freedom) GUI tools that allow me to export data from one relational database into files (CSV, XML, ...) and to bulk import this data into another database. Both database might be from different vendors.

I'm already aware of tools that migrate schemas, like [liquibase](http://liquibase.org) and not searching for that.

Extra plus points if such a tool

- is written in Java and uses JDBC drivers
- is an eclipse plugin (because our other tools are also eclipse based)
- allows all kinds of filtering and modification of the data during import or export
- can handle large (as in giga- or terabytes) data sets
- can be scheduled
- can continue an interrupted import/export

Similar questions:

- [Export large amounts of binary data from one SQL database and import it into another database of the same schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885203/export-large-amounts-of-binary-data-from-one-sql-database-and-import-it-into-ano)

It seems that the [WBExport](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/command-export.html) and [WBImport](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/command-import.html) commands of [SQLWorkbench](http://www.sql-workbench.net) are very good candidates. I also need to look whether [ETL Tools](http://www.etltools.org/open-source-etl.html) like Pentaho ETL do this stuff.

Comment: Hate to say it, but one of the main close reasons is "Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: Whether the question is closed or not, I can tell you that I would be taking a hard look at Pentaho Data Integration.

Answer (score 0):

[CloverETL](http://www.cloveretl.com/) meets nearly all your requirements. With free version you can work with following databases: MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, MS SQL, Sybase, Oracle, and Derby.